# how to remove all the parent div using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div structure like this

```
<body>
  <div>
    <nav></nav>
    <nav></nav>
    <div>
      <div id=parent-conatiner>
        <div>
          <ul>
            <li></li>
            <li></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

now i want to remove all the parent element of the div **#parent-container** but not removing any element inside the **#parent-container** div,
i dont want to use clone and then include the element in the body because i use some kendo controls inside the #parent-container and the kendo controls stopped working when i use the cloned div
basically i dont want to use the following logic

```
var $cloned=$('#parent-conatiner')
$('body').empty();
$('body').append($cloned);
```

any help would be appreciated,
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6647736/how-to-delete-parent-element-using-jquery

Comment: you want to remove <nav></nav> ?

Comment: @LijnJohn does my answer suit your needs now

Comment: @MarkoMackic .... yeah!!! thank you for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the below method, all event bindings are kept intact.

```
$('#parent-conatiner').parentsUntil('body').replaceWith($('#parent-conatiner'));
```

Comment: dint try yet, but have you any idea y that doesn't work

Comment: if you remove the parents, you remove the element with it

Comment: i used .parents().remove() but it removes all the div including the #parent-container div, here is a fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/lijin_john/0oa8wdba/

Comment: logicly because when you remove the div then you remove all it's content

Comment: Y not try prevAll() as @MarkoMackic answered

Answer (score 0):

Use the jquery `unwrap()` function

or use the cloning method and eventdelegate you  kendo controls

another solution will be:

```
$('body').append($('#parent-conatiner'));
$('body div:last').prevAll().remove();
```

but this should be the same problem like the cloning

another option is detach()

```
var el = $('#parent-conatiner').detach();
$('body').empty().append(el);
```

Comment: unwarp() removes only the parent div, basically i want to remove all the parent div of #parent-container and upto the body element

Comment: use it multiple times