# jQuery closest() remove() on <a> doesn't work?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Please see this [page](https://www.datactory.com/data/autoparts4/query) which has this code:

```
<div class="pure-control-group query-brand-by-column">
    <!-- somethings else -->
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-1-24 control-group-sub">
        <a href="javascript:$(this).closest('.query-brand-by-column').remove();" class="pure-button danger">X</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Clicking the X link should remove its ancestor `div.query-brand-by-column` as a whole but somehow it's not working. I've checked jQuery docs and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6647788/49318) and the code seems absolutely all right to me but it simply doesn't work. Any idea?

Comment: `this` is not the link within the `href` attribute. It’s `window`.

Comment: `href="javascript:..."` is a long out-of-date technique. Don't do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` in `href` doesn't refers to anchor element, thus it doesn't work. It refers to `window`.

You should bind element event handler using jQuery.

*Script*

```
$(document).on('click', '.pure-button danger' function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).closest('.query-brand-by-column').remove();
});
```

*HTML*

```
<div class="pure-control-group query-brand-by-column">
    <!-- somethings else -->
    <div class="pure-u-1 pure-u-sm-1-24 control-group-sub">
        <a href="#" class="pure-button danger">X</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I will not recommended, However you can use inline `onclick` handler.

```
<a onclick="$(this).closest('.query-brand-by-column').remove();" href='#' class="pure-button danger">X</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

Detach your javascript from your html and remove your item with a click event, right now you aren't triggering any click events:

```
<script>
$(function(){
 $('.pure-form').on('click','.query-brand-by-column a',function(){//this will create and delegate your click event to work on dynamically created items 
  $(this).closest('.query-brand-by-column').remove();
 });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is your answer, Enjoy

```
  <a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return $(this).closest('.query-brand-by-column').remove();" class="pure-button danger">X</a>
```